# Various errors while I'm trying to download a file from google drive from within a docker container

Tags: docker, google-drive-api, containers

I'm trying to download a file saved on my google drive using the ADD command inside my docker container. The ID of the file is "**1WbJuXFvbsOLkt-rKO50JEKu8lKS9LRV_**" and the file name is **2019-09-26-raspbian-buster-lite.img**. The command that I have added inside the container is :

```
ADD https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WbJuXFvbsOLkt-rKO50JEKu8lKS9LRV_/2019-09-26-raspbian-buster-lite.img .
```

The error message that comes from docker is :

> ADD failed: failed to GET
> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WbJuXFvbsOLkt-rKO50JEKu8lKS9LRV_/2019-09-26-raspbian-buster-lite.img
> with status 404 Not Found: Pagina non
> trovata<metaname="referrer" content="origin">/* Copyright 2021 Google Inc. All
> Rights Reserved.
> */.goog-inline-block{position:relative;display:-moz-inline-box;display:inline-block}*
> html .goog-inline-block{display:inline}*:first-child+html
> .goog-inline-block{display:inline}#drive-logo{margin:18px
> 0;position:absolute;white-space:nowrap}.docs-drivelogo-img{background-image:url('//ssl.gstatic.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_116x41dp.png');background-size:116px
> 41px;display:inline-block;height:41px;vertical-align:bottom;width:116px}.docs-drivelogo-text{color:#000;display:inline-block;opacity:0.54;text-decoration:none;font-family:'Product
> Sans',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:32px;text-rendering:optimizeLegibility;position:relative;top:-6px;left:-7px;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale}@media
> (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:1.5),(min-resolution:144dpi){.docs-drivelogo-img{background-image:url('//ssl.gstatic.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_116x41dp.png')}}body {background-color:
> #fff; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 13px; margin: 0; padding: 0;}a, a:link, a:visited {color: #112ABB;}.errorMessage
> {font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold; line-height:
> 150%;} DriveImpossibile aprire il file in questo momento.
>
> Verifica
> l'indirizzo e riprova.
>
> **Aumenta la tua produttività con Google
> Drive**
>
> Le app in Google Drive rendono più facile creare,
> salvare e condividere online documenti, fogli di lavoro, presentazioni
> e altro ancora.
>
> Per ulteriori informazioni,consulta [drive.google.com/start/apps](https://drive.google.com/start/apps).
>
> html {height: 100%; overflow:
> auto;}body {height: 100%; overflow: auto;}#outerContainer {margin:
> auto; max-width: 750px;}#innerContainer {margin-bottom: 20px;
> margin-left: 40px; margin-right: 40px; margin-top: 80px; position:
> relative;}</html

The working link for the file is :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WbJuXFvbsOLkt-rKO50JEKu8lKS9LRV_/view?usp=sharing

I want to get this file inside the docker container. Can you give me some help to configure docker correctly to achieve this goal ? thanks.

Comment: I don't understand. You state the working link at the bottom of the post, but have a different link in your ADD command. Why don't you use the working link in the ADD command?

Comment: why it is different ???? excuse me I don't see any difference...

Comment: Your `ADD` line includes the local file name in the URL, but the "working link" doesn't.

Comment: Note found means it does not exist so what ever user you are using to access google drive that user doesnt have access.   without seeing your code and how you are authorizing to google drive its hard to be able to help you

Comment: you can give a look at this : https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/sfR94PBzTh/ and at this : https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/sC84HTfwjs/